# Why does my metal material looks completely black on meshes?

Tags: c++, graphics, raytracing

I was working on my ray tracer written in C++ following this series of books: [Ray Tracing in One Weekend](https://raytracing.github.io).
I started working a little bit on my own trying to implement features that weren't described in the book, like a BVH tree builder using SAH, transforms, triangles and meshes.

*NOTE: The BVH implementation is based on two main resources which are this article: [Bounding Volume Hierarchies](https://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Primitives_and_Intersection_Acceleration/Bounding_Volume_Hierarchies) and [C-Ray](https://github.com/vkoskiv/c-ray/) (A ray tracer written in C).*

After I implemented all of that I noticed that there was some weirdness while trying to use some materials on meshes. For example, as the title says, the metal material looks completely black:
[image: How the metal material should look like]
[image: How the metal material looks like on meshes]

In the first image you can see how the metal material should look like and in the second one you can see how it looks like on meshes.

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out what the issue was but I couldn't find it and I couldn't find a way of tracking it.

If you want to take a look at the code for more clarity the ray tracer is on GitHub at https://github.com/ITHackerstein/RayTracer.
The branch on which I'm implementing meshes is `meshes`.

To replicate my build environment I suggest you follow this build instructions:

`$ git clone https://github.com/ITHackerstein/RayTracer`

`$ cd RayTracer`

`$ git checkout meshes`

`$ mkdir build`

`$ cd build`

`$ cmake ..`

`$ make`

`$ mkdir tests`

At this point you're almost ready to go except you need the TOML scene file an the OBJ file I'm using which are these two:

- [boh.toml](https://pastebin.com/raw/NAFncWGu) (Scene file)
- [teapot.obj](https://pastebin.com/raw/aVsp3KDz) (Teapot OBJ file)

Download them and place them in the `build/tests` and after that make sure you are in the `build` folder and run it using the following command:

`$ ./RayTracer tests/boh.toml`

After it finishes running you should have a `tests/boh.ppm` file which is the resulting image file stored using PPM format. If you don't have a software that let's you open it there are multiple viewers online.

*NOTE: My platform is Linux, I didn't test it on Windows or Mac OS.*

---

**EDIT**

> Does the mesh work with other materials?

[image: How the lambertian diffuse material looks like on a teapot]
[image: How the lambertian diffuse material looks line on a torus]
[image: How the lambertian diffuse material looks like on a sphere]

So as you can in the first image and especially in the second one we have we have some darker rectangular spots, and also the lighting seems kinda messed up. In the third image you have an idea of how it works on a normal primitive.

Comment: I did not have time to read or try your ray tracer but a similar problem is described in [moving Frostbite to PBR](https://seblagarde.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/course_notes_moving_frostbite_to_pbr_v32.pdf) on page 61.  However, this is just a guess.

Comment: @Sebphil Alright, thanks I'll check it out.

Comment: Does the mesh work with other materials?

Comment: @NicoSchertler Not prorperly, so for example the diffuse material which should like a plain color all over the mesh, has some darker rectangular spots. I'll update the question with an example.

Comment: Not really a "minimal" repro.  Do you have ANY debugging details to share with us?  Can you imagine any kind of investigation that could help narrow down your problem?

Comment: @Wyck Ok, so I think the problem has to do with the normals and my main guess is that they are flipped, but it's just a guess and I can't really think of anything else, and that's the main reason why I've reached for help here. Anyway I'll do some tests in these days and update the question if I have any new information to share with you.

Comment: This is a debugging exercise.  It's rendering the geometry of the teapot mesh, but shading it black.  Where did the black color come from and why?  It seems plausible that you are executing a code path that you shouldn't be.  Change the program to fire a single ray into the teapot that shouldn't appear black.  Find the code that returns the black color and set a breakpoint.   Walk backwards examining all the logical checks that caused it to follow the branch that resulted in blackness.  At each step, make a statement about what you intend vs what actually happened.  Find the discrepancy.

Comment: @Wyck Ok, so I discovered that the reason it shaded the mesh black was that the `Metal::scatter` function returns false, and when that happens the `Tracer::trace_ray` method returns the emitted value of the material which is handled by `Material::emitted`, but in case of metal it return false, so it uses black as fall back. So I went ahead and looked at `Metal::scatter` and its return value it's handled by a dot product between the scattered ray's direction and the normal, and if it is greater than 0 (the angle between the two vectors is acute) then it returns true.

Comment: @Wyck So I tried one more thing, I set the `Metal::scatter` method to always return true and added a sphere inside the teapot, and the result was that I could see through the teapot and I could see the sphere. So I guess that the `scattered` ray points inside the teapot rather than outside as I would expect.

Comment: @Wyck I found out another thing, I started investigating on way I could see through the teapot and found out that the only way it could have happened is when the normal vector is zero or almost zero, and in fact the normal value that reaches the `Metal::scatter` is very close to zero. So I started logging the values of the normal and noticed that they become zero in `Tracer::trace_ray`, but I still have to find out why. Anyway thanks for the tips you gave me, they really helped me figure out how to debug these kind of issues, since i've never really worked with computer graphics before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out thanks to the tips that @Wyck gave me.
The problem was in the normals, I noticed that the `Metal::scatter` method received a normal that was almost zero. So that's why it was returning black.
After some logging, I found out that the `Instance::intersects_ray` method was not normalizing the transformed normal vector, and that's what caused the issue. So, in the end, the solution was simpler than I thought it would be.